cleanup_tokenization_spaces issue in Flux running in ComfyUI
I'm getting the issue below with Flux in ComfyUI and it points to this bug (https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/cleaup-tokenization-spaces-error/102749). What is the solution to resolve it? Do I set the cleanup_tokenization_spaces parameter to false somewhere?
Full terminal output below:
got prompt
model weight dtype torch.bfloat16, manual cast: None
model_type FLUX
/home/garrett/AI/ComfyUI/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:1601: FutureWarning: `clean_up_tokenization_spaces` was not set. It will be set to `True` by default. This behavior will be depracted in transformers v4.45, and will be then set to `False` by default. For more details check this issue: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/31884
  warnings.warn(
./launch.sh: line 7: 47378 Killed                  python3 main.py


I'm facing the same issue in my Python service in this block:
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    pretrained_model_name_or_path="{path}",
    local_files_only=True)

The warning disappears when I modify it like this:
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    pretrained_model_name_or_path="{path}",
    local_files_only=True,
    clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)

I hope it helps.

Where do you modify this? I've checked the file mentioned in the terminal (ComfyUI/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py) and this is mentioned several times but only in comments. Not sure how to trace the issue back to it's origins in ComfyUI.

Garrett I'm directly using LLM in my project, so I can set it right away. I guess comfyUI itself doing the same thing behind the scenes, but not setting this parameter. Maybe you can find where it creates the tokenizer and modify its code, or override it somehow

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
